# How can I get my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to plot correctly over my RasterLayer

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile

I've got a problem when I try to plot the following.

I've created a mask of my study area with raster cell ID's and a shapefile with the country outlines of my study area.
The shapefile was created by merging the shapefiles of the countries, and then cropping it to the study area. (which was needed because the world countries shapefile wasn't detailed enough)

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

#load Mask
sa.ID <- raster("Masks/sa.ID.asc")
proj4string(sa.ID) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
sa.ID

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 177, 266, 47082  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : 118.8333, 141, -9.166667, 5.583333  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0  
data source : ....\Masks\sa.ID.asc 
names       : sa.ID 

#load countries shapefile
countries.ra <- readOGR(dsn="diva-gis/Adm areas", layer="countries.ra")
countries.ra

class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 4 
extent      : 118.8, 141, -9.2, 5.6  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 70
names       : GADMID, ISO,  NAME_ENGLI,    NAME_ISO,    NAME_FAO,  NAME_LOCAL,                                                                                                       NAME_OBSOL,                  NAME_VARIA, NAME_NONLA,                   NAME_FRENC,     NAME_SPANI,            NAME_RUSSI,          NAME_ARABI, NAME_CHINE, WASPARTOF, ... 
min values  :    103, IDN,  East Timor,   INDONESIA,   Indonesia,   Indonesia,                                                      British New Guinea|German New Guinea|New Britain|New Guinea, East Timor|Portuguese Timor,         NA,                   IndonÃ©sie,      Filipinas, ????? Â— ????? ??????, ????? ????? ???????,        ???,        NA, ... 
max values  :    222, TLS, Philippines, TIMOR-LESTE, Timor-Leste, Timor-Leste, Dutch Borneo|Dutch East Indies|Dutch New Guinea|East Indies|Netherlands Indies|West New Guinea|Nederlands IndiÃ«,                 Philippines,         NA, Timor-Leste (Timor Oriental), Timor Oriental,       ????????? ?????,           ?????????,    ???????,        NA, ...
```

Now I try to plot the mask with the country layer on top

```
plot(sa.ID, xlim=c(118.8,141), ylim=c(-9.2,5.6), axes=TRUE)
plot(countries.ra, add=T)
```

Initially, the plot I get looks fine, but when the extent of the plot window is changed, or when I try to save it, the countries shape changes with it instead of staying where it should be (see [sa.ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HiRd.jpg) )

but somehow, when I change it around and plot

```
plot(sa.ID, xlim=c(118.8,141), ylim=c(-9.2,5.6), axes=TRUE)
plot(countries.ra, add=T)
```

the countries shape does stay put (see [sa.ID.inverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYYhu.jpg)).
However, as I need the clear lines on top, I really need the first one to work.

Can anybody help me? Because I really can't see what I might be doing wrong...

eta: I have the same problem with my range mask (which has values for every raster cell) and with the world country shapefile

Comment: Long shot, but have you tried adding the xlim and ylim arguments to the `countries.ra` plot? Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: I suspect that you get the problem when you extent your graphique in windows.  Skip that all togethere by directly saving your graph (with, for example, `png`, do `?png`). You can specified the width and height of you figure directly (in pixel or inchs).

Comment: I'm with @Bastien here. This is an issue that is going to be persistent whenever you are plotting in base R. Base R won't redraw the plot based on your newly defined plot window dimensions. If you we're plotting this in RStudio, it wouldn't be an issue. If things are landing where they are supposed to initially, you're fine.

Comment: @dash2 thanks for the welcome. Adding the arguments to the countries.ra plot unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim, thanks for your reply. I see I forgot to say I'm working in Rstudio. I'm trying to save the plot pictures as a pdf file (which I need for the journal I'm writing for), but as I check the preview I can see it shifted...

Comment: @Bastien, thanks for your reply. Would you happen to know if I can also save as a `pdf`  (which I need for the journal I'm writing for) or `tif` (next best thing) with specified dimensions?

Comment: @annisea, for tif, do `?tiff`.  It's on the same help page as `png` (with `bmp`and `jpeg`).  For pdf, do `?pdf`  (can you see the pattern here... ;) ).  All those fonctions works basically the same with sligth differences in available options and default.  Basically, start your device with, lets say, `tiff()`, write your plots (`plot`, `points`, `legend`, etc.) and then close the device with `dev.off()`.  redo util you find all the right settings.

Comment: @Bastien Thanks! I got it to work ^^

Comment: So I just want to verify, even now that you've got it exporting as *.pdf, its still shifted?

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim If I save it using the method mentioned by Bastien (fiddling with the size parameters): no. If I try to export it from the plot window in Rstudio: yes, even when I give the same size parameters as with the other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on @Bastien's comment, I think you might try using:

```
plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = "", asp = NA, ...)
```

to designate the dimensions of your plot window. I'm not sure what how you want your plots to appear, but something to the effect of:

```
plot.window(xlim=c(118.8333, 141), ylim=( -9.166667, 5.583333))
```

If you designate these values, it *should* force R to redraw the plot window correctly each time.